# Какие зависимости у perl модуля «WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS»?

Tags: perl

Друзья, имеется сервер на ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Никак не могу на нем установить модуль из cpan, не понятно что ему нужно.
Причем модуль без проблем устанавливается рабочий ноут, машины коллег, и рабочий сервер.

Лог cpanm:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7004 on perl 5.014002 built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.07
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching install on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on install
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/install-0.01.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking install-0.01.tar.gz
Entering install-0.01
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.98)
Configuring install-0.01
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for install
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.98)
Building and testing install-0.01
cp lib/install.pm blib/lib/install.pm
Manifying blib/man3/install.3pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/install.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.04 CPU)
Result: PASS
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/install.pm
Installing /usr/local/man/man3/install.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/lib/perl/5.14/perllocal.pod
-> OK
Successfully installed install-0.01
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int/.meta/install-0.01/install.json
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int/.meta/install-0.01/MYMETA.json
Searching WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06.tar.gz
Entering WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.98)
Configuring WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06
Running Makefile.PL
(Re)Creating lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/Examples.pm
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have File::Copy 0 ... Yes (2.21)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.39)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.3301)
Checking if you have HTTP::Response 0 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have File::Find 0 ... Yes (1.19)
Checking if you have WWW::Mechanize::Link 0 ... Yes (undef)
Checking if you have HTML::Selector::XPath 0 ... Yes (0.16)
Checking if you have File::Path 0 ... Yes (2.08_01)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.82)
Checking if you have HTTP::Daemon 0 ... Yes (6.01)
Checking if you have Object::Import 0 ... Yes (1.004)
Checking if you have LWP::Simple 0 ... Yes (6.00)
Checking if you have Selenium::Remote::Driver 0.18 ... Yes (0.2101)
Building and testing WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS.pm blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS.pm
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/hub_register.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/hub_register.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/har.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/har.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/status_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/status_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/session.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/session.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/parseuri.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/parseuri.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/config.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/config.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/logger.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/logger.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/DSL.pm blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/DSL.pm
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/Examples.pm blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/Examples.pm
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/inputs.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/inputs.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/shutdown_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/shutdown_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/webelement_request_handler.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/request_handlers/webelement_request_handler.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/console++.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/console++.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/errors.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/errors.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/main.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/main.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/find_elements.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/find_elements.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_async_script.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_async_script.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/drag.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/drag.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear_session_storage.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear_session_storage.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/find_element.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/find_element.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear_local_storage.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/clear_local_storage.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_appcache_status.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_appcache_status.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/focus_on_element.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/focus_on_element.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/click.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/click.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/uuid.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/uuid.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_sql.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_sql.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/double_click.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/double_click.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_script.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_script.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/active_element.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/active_element.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_value_of_css_property.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_value_of_css_property.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_size.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_size.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_location.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_location.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_text.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_text.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_keys.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_keys.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_attribute.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_attribute.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_attribute_value.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_attribute_value.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_current_position.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_current_position.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_keys.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_keys.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_location_in_view.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_location_in_view.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_size.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_size.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_size.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_session_storage_size.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/get_local_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/set_session_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/set_session_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_selected.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_selected.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/remove_session_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/remove_session_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/pinch.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/pinch.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/move_mouse.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/move_mouse.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_online.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_online.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_enabled.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_enabled.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_displayed.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/is_displayed.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/right_click.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/right_click.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/remove_local_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/remove_local_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/scroll_into_view.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/scroll_into_view.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/lastupdate blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/lastupdate
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/set_local_storage_item.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/set_local_storage_item.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/scroll_mouse.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/scroll_mouse.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/rotate.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/rotate.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/webelementlocator.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/webelementlocator.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/submit.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/submit.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/webdriver_atoms.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/webdriver_atoms.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/type.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/type.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/swipe.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/swipe.js
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/Selector.pm blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/Selector.pm
cp lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/tap.js blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/tap.js
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS::DSL.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS::Examples.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::Selector.3pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/00-load.t t/49-mech-get-file.t t/49-mech-nav.t t/50-click.t t/50-follow-link.t t/50-form-with-fields.t t/50-form2.t t/50-highlight-nodes.t t/50-load-and-load.t t/50-mech-content.t t/50-mech-ct.t t/50-mech-encoding.t t/50-mech-error.t t/50-mech-forms.t t/50-mech-get-nocache.t t/50-mech-get.t t/50-mech-new-dsl.t t/50-mech-post.t t/50-mech-status.t t/50-popup.t t/51-mech-form-with-fields.t t/51-mech-set-content.t t/51-mech-submit.t t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t t/56-render-content.t t/60-mech-custom-headers.t t/70-real-status.t t/99-changes.t t/99-examples.t t/99-manifest.t t/99-pod.t t/99-todo.t t/99-unix-text.t t/99-versions.t
# Testing WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS 0.06, Perl 5.014002
# AutoLoader 5.74
# B 1.29
# Carp 1.3301
# Class::XSAccessor 1.19
# Class::XSAccessor::Heavy 1.19
# Compress::Raw::Bzip2 2.064
# Compress::Raw::Zlib 2.065
# Config <unknown>
# Data::Dumper 2.151
# Devel::GlobalDestruction 0.12
# DynaLoader 1.13
# Exporter 5.70
# Exporter::Heavy 5.70
# Fcntl 1.11
# File::Basename 2.82
# File::Glob 1.13
# File::GlobMapper 1.000
# File::Spec 3.47
# File::Spec::Unix 3.47
# FileHandle 2.02
# HTML::Selector::XPath 0.16
# HTTP::Date 6.02
# HTTP::Headers 6.05
# HTTP::Message 6.06
# HTTP::Request 6.00
# HTTP::Response 6.04
# HTTP::Status 6.03
# IO 1.25_04
# IO::Compress::Adapter::Bzip2 2.064
# IO::Compress::Adapter::Deflate 2.064
# IO::Compress::Adapter::Identity 2.064
# IO::Compress::Base 2.064
# IO::Compress::Base::Common 2.064
# IO::Compress::Bzip2 2.064
# IO::Compress::Gzip::Constants 2.064
# IO::Compress::RawDeflate 2.064
# IO::Compress::Zip 2.064
# IO::Compress::Zip::Constants 2.064
# IO::Compress::Zlib::Extra 2.064
# IO::File 1.15
# IO::Handle 1.31
# IO::Seekable 1.1
# Import::Into 1.002004
# JSON 2.61
# JSON::PP 2.27203
# LWP 6.07
# LWP::MemberMixin <unknown>
# LWP::Protocol 6.06
# LWP::UserAgent 6.06
# List::Util 1.39
# Method::Generate::Accessor <unknown>
# Method::Generate::Constructor <unknown>
# Module::Runtime 0.014
# Moo 1.005
# Moo::HandleMoose::_TypeMap <unknown>
# Moo::Object <unknown>
# Moo::_Utils <unknown>
# Moo::_mro <unknown>
# Moo::sification <unknown>
# Net::Ping 2.41
# POSIX 1.24
# PerlIO 1.07
# Scalar::Util 1.39
# SelectSaver 1.02
# Selenium::Remote::Commands 0.2101
# Selenium::Remote::Driver 0.2101
# Selenium::Remote::ErrorHandler 0.2101
# Selenium::Remote::RemoteConnection 0.2101
# Selenium::Remote::WebElement 0.2101
# Socket 2.014
# Storable 2.51
# Sub::Defer 1.005
# Sub::Exporter::Progressive 0.001011
# Sub::Name 0.07
# Sub::Quote 1.005
# Symbol 1.07
# Test::Builder 1.001003
# Test::Builder::Module 1.001003
# Test::More 1.001003
# Tie::Hash 1.04
# Time::HiRes 1.9726
# Time::Local 1.2300
# Try::Tiny 0.22
# URI 1.64
# URI::Escape 3.31
# WWW::Mechanize::Link <unknown>
# WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS 0.06
# WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::Selector 0.06
# XSLoader 0.16
# base 2.18
# bytes 1.04
# constant 1.27
# feature 1.20
# mro 1.07
# overload 1.13
# re 0.18
# strict 1.04
# strictures 1.005004
# utf8 1.09
# vars 1.02
# warnings 1.12
# warnings::register 1.02
t/00-load.t ................... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
# Loading /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06/t/49-mech-get-file.html

#   Failed test '49-mech-get-file.html'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 41.

#   Failed test 'We loaded the right file (javascript 0)'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 42.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '49-mech-get-file.html'
# <html><head></head><body></body></html>
# Loading /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06/t/49-mech-get-file.html

#   Failed test '49-mech-get-file.html'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 41.

#   Failed test 'We loaded the right file (javascript 1)'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 42.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '49-mech-get-file.html'
# <html><head></head><body></body></html>

#   Failed test '49-mech-get-file.html'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 58.

#   Failed test 'We loaded the right file'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 59.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '49-mech-get-file.html'
Use of uninitialized value $ct in substitution (s///) at /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS.pm line 860.

#   Failed test 'The local file gets identified as HTML'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 61.
# <html><head></head><body></body></html>

#   Failed test '49-mech-get-file-lc-ct.html'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 65.

#   Failed test 'We loaded the right file'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 66.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '49-mech-get-file-lc-ct.html'
Use of uninitialized value $ct in substitution (s///) at /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS.pm line 860.

#   Failed test 'The local file gets identified as HTML even with a weird-cased http-equiv attribute'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 68.
# <html><head></head><body></body></html>
# Looks like you failed 10 tests of 12.
t/49-mech-get-file.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 10 (wstat 2560, 0xa00)
Failed 10/12 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
# Going back
# Going forward
t/49-mech-nav.t ............... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
# Looks like you planned 27 tests but ran 16.
t/50-click.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 11/27 subtests 
    (less 15 skipped subtests: 1 okay)
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-follow-link.t ............ ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
No elements found for form number 1 at t/50-form-with-fields.t line 36.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
t/50-form-with-fields.t ....... 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 8/8 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
No elements found for form number 2 at t/50-form2.t line 33.
# Looks like you planned 13 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
t/50-form2.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 12/13 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'

#   Failed test 'We highlighted one element'
#   at t/50-highlight-nodes.t line 41.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
t/50-highlight-nodes.t ........ 
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/2 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-load-and-load.t .......... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-content.t ........... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-ct.t ................ ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
Use of uninitialized value in uc at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 39.

#   Failed test 'mixi_jp_index.html has encoding EUC-JP'
#   at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 39.
#          got: ''
#     expected: 'EUC-JP'
# 39

#   Failed test 'Partial expression gets found in UTF-8 content'
#   at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 41.
#                   '<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
#     doesn't match '(?^u:\x{30DF}\x{30AF}\x{30B7}\x{30A3})'
Use of uninitialized value in uc at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 39.

#   Failed test 'sophos_co_jp_index.html has encoding SHIFT_JIS'
#   at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 39.
#          got: ''
#     expected: 'SHIFT_JIS'
# 39

#   Failed test 'Partial expression gets found in UTF-8 content'
#   at t/50-mech-encoding.t line 41.
#                   '<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
#     doesn't match '(?^u:\x{30B0}\x{30ED}\x{30FC}\x{30D0}\x{30EB})'
# Looks like you failed 4 tests of 4.
t/50-mech-encoding.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 4 (wstat 1024, 0x400)
Failed 4/4 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-error.t ............. ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'

#   Failed test 'We found one form'
#   at t/50-mech-forms.t line 38.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'
Can't call method "get_attribute" on an undefined value at t/50-mech-forms.t line 40.
# Looks like you planned 14 tests but ran 3.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 3.
t/50-mech-forms.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 12/14 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-get-nocache.t ....... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-get.t ............... ok
sh: 1: phantomjs-versionsphantomjs-1.9.7-windowsphantomjs: not found
t/50-mech-new-dsl.t ........... skipped: Couldn't connect to PhantomJS: Selenium server did not return proper status at (eval 91) line 61.
t/50-mech-post.t .............. skipped: POST requests via Selenium/ghostdriver/PhantomJS are currently unsupported :-/
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/50-mech-status.t ............ ok
t/50-popup.t .................. skipped: Opening windows are not yet tracked
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
No elements found for form with fields [r] at t/51-mech-form-with-fields.t line 35.
# Looks like you planned 5 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
t/51-mech-form-with-fields.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 4/5 subtests 
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/51-mech-set-content.t ....... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/51-mech-submit.t ............ ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'

#   Failed test '53-mech-capture-js-noerror.html'
#   at t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t line 39.

#   Failed test 'We loaded the right file (javascript 1)'
#   at t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t line 40.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '53-mech-capture-js-noerror.html'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 19.
t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/19 subtests 
    (less 14 skipped subtests: 3 okay)
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/56-render-content.t ......... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
t/60-mech-custom-headers.t .... ok
# Testing with /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
# PhantomJS version '1.9.7', ghostdriver version '1.1.0'
# http://localhost:58163/
t/70-real-status.t ............ ok
# Checking for version 0.06
t/99-changes.t ................ ok
t/99-examples.t ............... ok
t/99-manifest.t ............... ok
t/99-pod.t .................... skipped: Test::Pod required for testing POD
t/99-todo.t ................... ok
t/99-unix-text.t .............. ok
# Checking for $VERSION= '0.06';
t/99-versions.t ............... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/49-mech-get-file.t        (Wstat: 2560 Tests: 12 Failed: 10)
  Failed tests:  2-11
  Non-zero exit status: 10
t/50-click.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 16 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 27 tests but ran 16.
t/50-form-with-fields.t     (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
t/50-form2.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 13 tests but ran 1.
t/50-highlight-nodes.t      (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/50-mech-encoding.t        (Wstat: 1024 Tests: 4 Failed: 4)
  Failed tests:  1-4
  Non-zero exit status: 4
t/50-mech-forms.t           (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 14 tests but ran 3.
t/51-mech-form-with-fields.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 5 tests but ran 1.
t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 19 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  4-5
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=34, Tests=188, 126 wallclock secs ( 0.22 usr  0.07 sys + 25.36 cusr  4.20 csys = 29.85 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 9/34 test programs. 18/188 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
1 distribution installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Пакет не установился, так как  не прошел тест.

```
# Loading /root/.cpanm/work/1406453179.18706/WWW-Mechanize-PhantomJS-0.06/t/49-mech-get-file.html

#   Failed test '49-mech-get-file.html'
#   at t/49-mech-get-file.t line 41.
```

Не смогло загрузить файл. А вот почему - это не понятно.

Comment: Посмотрел в тестах, оказалось не хватало пары стандартных модулей, вроде JSON::PP. Но устанавливаться он после все равно не стал...

Comment: >устанавливаться он после все равно не стал

А выражается это в чём-то конкретном, или "дорогие учёные, у нас тут подземный стук?"